# Two Side-by-Side Tables in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to display two tables, side-by-side, in Bootstrap 3?

Each tried making each one col-md-6 and, although it shrinks the width, they don't wrap next to each other (instead one is on top of the other in the full-width view).

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">Latest Incidents</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to wrap each table in a col-6 div, as opposed to applying col-6 to the table itself. Here is your code with col-xs-6 wrapped around:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <h2 class="sub-header">Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">...
```

**And here it is in action: http://www.bootply.com/lbrQZF3152**

Comment: This won't work with long text but you can do this. Add style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%" to <table> and <td style="word-wrap: break-word">

Comment: it works for me but have one issue, the height of the tables is different. any solution https://drive.google.com/open?id=10mm8wgxqfh9PtOWPmYmtqhQTE32vTuX8

Comment: add another row:) seriously though, if there are a different number of rows, it will be a different height.

Comment: if you really want to solve this somehow, you could add blank rows or something, but that's either a manual thing, or something that deserves its own question

Answer (score 18):

Add your col-md-6 class to each wrapping div so you have this structure:

```
<div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Shawn and kmo already pointed out that using `col-md-6` class will make this work. 
I would also like to add that if you are doing this inside an `ul` and `li` things might break.

The solution is quite simple though. Just add a div with the class `row` before:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
      <table>...</table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
      <table>...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work both tables are overlaping

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution. this solution worked for everyone.
use a container (like div), this will contain every table you have, after this, to this container you will put:
style="display: flex "
its almost finish, you will have the tables in one line, the last thing is put borders, and its all.
flex will positioning your tables in equal parts, filling all the window you have, no matter the window size.
reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox
I post a simple example:

```
<div style="display: flex ">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" colspan="3">data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" colspan="3">data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```